# C++ Forced to do a weird cast to get rid of "expression should be a modifiable lvalue"

Tags: c++, enums, casting

I just faced a strange enum assignation problem and I thought you could have helped me out. I have an enum like this:

```
enum LIB_EDXENGINE CameraFeatureDataType
    {
        CFDT_ENUMERATION,
        CFDT_64BITS_UINT,
        CFDT_64BITS_INT,
        CFDT_64BITS_FLOAT,
        CFDT_BOOLEAN,
        CFDT_32BITS_UINT,
        CFDT_32BITS_INT,
        CFDT_32BITS_FLOAT,
    };
```

And I have a class with an instance of this enum.
**EDITED:**

```
const CameraFeatureDataType & LibEDX::CVBGenicamFeature2::GetFeatureType() const
{
    switch (m_eNodeType)
    {
    case NT_Boolean:
        m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_BOOLEAN;
        break;
    case NT_Integer:
        m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_64BITS_INT;
        break;
    case NT_Float:
        m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_64BITS_FLOAT;
        break;
    case NT_Enumeration:
        m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_ENUMERATION;
        break;
    }
    return m_eCameraFeatureDataType;
}
```

The only solution that I found to get rid of the error is to cast the member variable to its own type, which is weird I think.
**EDITED TOO:**

```
const CameraFeatureDataType & LibEDX::CVBGenicamFeature2::GetFeatureType() const
{
    switch (m_eNodeType)
    {
    case NT_Boolean:
        (CameraFeatureDataType)m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_BOOLEAN;
        break;
    case NT_Integer:
        (CameraFeatureDataType)m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_64BITS_INT;
        break;
    case NT_Float:
        (CameraFeatureDataType)m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_64BITS_FLOAT;
        break;
    case NT_Enumeration:
        (CameraFeatureDataType)m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_ENUMERATION;
        break;
    }
    return m_eCameraFeatureDataType;
}
```

Comment: Great, so you have a specific error in mind. Can you post a [mcve] so we could reproduce it? Your code snippet doesn't give anything away.

Comment: Regardless, you are missing several `break` statements.

Comment: Is the switch-statement possibly in a `const`-qualified member function?

Comment: @BoPersson - Good spot! But then the cast to a value shuold be a problem in and off itself, no?

Comment: My crystal ball says there's something you're not telling us. Make your example complete. https://ideone.com/fmVdrD

Comment: Could it be that this is in a `const` method?

Comment: Is the code you’ve shown part of a `const` member function?

Comment: Yes, guys, thanks you spotted it ! But what happens if I cast then ?

Comment: By casting to a value (not a reference) you are then modifying a temporary copy of the member. The member itself remains unchanged.

Comment: Do either of those functions really need to be member functions or use a member variable? I normally would expect a get function to not modify any data, I'm just asking about something that should already be set. You could just as easily return a local and make those free functions. This is especially true since you pass no new data into the function.  Why isn't the proper value of m_eCameraFeatureDataType  set when m_eNodeType changes?

Comment: I could post the error itself, but I work into a french IDE so I thought that was not appropriate.

Comment: I tried to create the instance in my method in the first place, but I can't return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: So then the question is, why is it a reference? Do you expect the caller to change it? If you must modify it in a const function make it mutable.

Comment: I've not coded it all myself. I'm actually trying to figure out the point of returning a reference. Is it to done so you can modify the return value and it will affect the member variable ? (if you return one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared method as const and then you do member attribute modification:

```
const CameraFeatureDataType & LibEDX::CVBGenicamFeature2::GetFeatureType() const
{
switch (m_eNodeType)
{
case NT_Boolean:
    this->m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_BOOLEAN;
    break;
case NT_Integer:
    this->m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_64BITS_INT;
    break;
case NT_Float:
    this->m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_64BITS_FLOAT;
    break;
case NT_Enumeration:
    this->m_eCameraFeatureDataType = CFDT_ENUMERATION;
    break;
}
return this->m_eCameraFeatureDataType;
}
```

You propably should write:

```
const CameraFeatureDataType & LibEDX::CVBGenicamFeature2::GetFeatureType() const
{
switch (m_eNodeType)
{
case NT_Boolean:
    return CFDT_BOOLEAN;
case NT_Integer:
    return CFDT_64BITS_INT;
case NT_Float:
    return CFDT_64BITS_FLOAT;
case NT_Enumeration:
    return CFDT_ENUMERATION;
}
return CFDT_UNKNOWN;//change to default value
}
```

Comment: It did the trick ! Something like this was there in the first place. But I was missing the return value outside the switch and I believed there was some warnings by the compiler, they are gone now. Thanks !

Comment: By the way, the reference was like a "link" to a variable for me, to access it out of the method. I don't understand how CFDT_BOOLEAN for example, is considered as reference. Enums are different from classical variables, that's why I was more confused than a reference to an std::string for example (which is instanciated).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to modify a member variable in a `const` method.

This is what your method would look like normally:

```
CameraFeatureDataType LibEDX::CVBGenicamFeature2::GetFeatureType() const
{
    switch (m_eNodeType)
    {
    case NT_Boolean:
        return CFDT_BOOLEAN;
    case NT_Integer:
        return CFDT_64BITS_INT;
    case NT_Float:
        return CFDT_64BITS_FLOAT;
    case NT_Enumeration:
        return CFDT_ENUMERATION;
    default:
        // don't know either, you decide...
    }
}
```

I have no idea why you even have a member variable, or why you would return an enum value as a const reference. If you need one of those, you should think hard about *why* you need them. The keyword for changing a member variable in a `const`method is `mutable`.